# C: Reading multiple CSV files

Tags: c, csv

I need to read a CSV table and use its values for functions, but the `scanf()` function only reads the first column of the file. I also need the code to be able to read more than one file, not allowing me to specify the name of the file.  What would be the correct way of doing so?

**Example:**

CSV file line: `114 -0.44 -0.15385 -0.76293`

Code output: `114 0.00 0.00 0.00`

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tgmath.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    long sec;
    long wait = 0;
    int fall = 0;
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    double mag = 0.0;
    long i =0;

    while(1){
        scanf("%ld %lf %lf %lf", &sec, &x, &y, &z);
        mag = sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)+pow(z,2));
        break;
    }

    printf("%ld %lf %lf %lf\n", sec, x, y, z);

    output1(wait);
    output2(fall);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/wjutAL Just tried your code and it is working as expected.

Comment: Please give a true [mcve] (what are output1 and output2 here) and actual input and output. As said by Ajay, this code can read and print the example input!

Comment: Not to be too picky, but, CSV means Comma Separated Values, your example code doesn't separate values with commas, but with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows OS, you could use `dirent.h` and create an input directory, where you can store your input files.

Once you have the files you can do a proper handling and start reading lines from it. Since you have a csv file, you can use the `strtok` to break the line into tokens and then load your variables with them.

Answer (score 0):

The thing stopping you from reading multiple files, is that you're using stdin to read the data rather than opening the files you want? If you're going to be doing the same thing repeatedly but with different input (ie filenames) you should create a function, something along the lines of...

```
void myfunc(char *filename)
  {
  FILE *thefile;
  double x,y,z;
  long sec;

  thefile=fopen(filename,"r");
  if(thefile)
    {
    if(fscanf(thefile,"%ld %lf %lf %lf", &sec, &x, &y, &z)==4)
      {
      /* do stuff */
      }
    fclose(thefile);
    }
  }
```

and then in your main you could use the command line arguments to specify the file names like so

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
  {
  int i;
  for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
    {
    myfunc(argv[i]);
    }
  }
```